# Datepicker not showing calendar

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Trying to implement a datepicker and style it a bit better, so it all works fine, until i use the buttonImage option, I have the file calendar_add.png in my assets/images folder, but it doesn't load the image and when i look at the server, it shows

```
!! Invalid request
```

This is the code i'm using this for this. Any suggestions?

```
return $(this).datepicker({
    altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",   
    minDate: 0,   
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    showOn: "button",                                                     
    buttonImage: "<%= asset_path('calendar_add.png') %>",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    altField: $(this).next()
});
```

Just to add, i'm also using bootstrap and simple_form, maybe this is causing the issue? but it would seem that it shouldn't.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your file path may be wrong. Does asset_path go into the images folder all the time?

buttonImage: "<%= asset_path('/images/calendar_add.png') %>",

Comment: for some reason the console is saying is trying to pull this: GET http://localhost:3000/dash/customers_dash/%3C%=%20asset_path('/images/calendar_add.png')%20%%3E 
so is not really going into the assets folder...